# What was the point of the armbands in Never Let Me Go?

Tags: never-let-me-go

In the film *Never Let Me Go*, the camerawork made the scanning of the armbands that the donors wore quite obvious at several points (at school, at the cottages, and even at Kathy's apartment.

What was the point of these? What it anything more than recording when donors came and went?  If a donor ran away, it doesn't seem like having a record would really help with anything, since they have to actively scan them.

Does the novel expand on these devices more?

Answer (score 5):

When I saw the movie, I figured it was a tracking device.  It was another indicator that the donors' worldview was so limited that they never thought to run.  To all of them donation was inevitable, there was no other future for them.  In the movie you can also see this reflected in their quest, they don't seek to escape donating, just put it off for a while.